# UIGestureRecognizer is not working, even though i enable isUserInteractionEnabled

Tags: swift, uiimageview, isuserinteractionenabled

```
 lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectedProfileImage)))

    return imageView
}()

@objc func handleSelectedProfileImage() {
    print("fff")
}
```

**I follow the instruction on Youtube to set the action for uiimageView, but it can not print anything from the function, do not know what happen**

Comment: Try `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: yes, uitapgestureRecognizer it works, thank you Rajes